# How to close springboot default file-appender.xml?

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

My logback.xml content is as follow:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_TEMP" value="${user.home}/logs/cloudcanal/console"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <appender name="PROJECT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator>
            <Key>module</Key>
            <DefaultValue>console</DefaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="FILE-${module}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
                <File>${user.home}/logs/cloudcanal/console/${module}.log</File>
                <rollingPolicy
                        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                    <!-- rollover daily -->
                    <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/logs/cloudcanal/console/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}/${module}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz
                    </fileNamePattern>
                    <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                        <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
                        <maxFileSize>512MB</maxFileSize>
                    </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
                    <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
                </rollingPolicy>
                <encoder>
                    <pattern>
                        %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{56} - %msg%n
                    </pattern>
                </encoder>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>
    

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="PROJECT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

When I start springboot I find there exist two log file called console.log and spring.log whose content is the same. I check some document and know that spring.log is generated by springboot's file appender(file-appender.xml). Can I only use my own PROJECT appender?

New edited at 2020/11/30
What I really want to achieve is to rename the default spring.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer myself. Just using the following config in spring config properties or yaml file.

```
logging.file.name=console.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding -

```
logging.config=logback.xml
```

on the property file (application.properties)
and see

Comment: I tried and spring.log file still have duplicated log output

Comment: can you please add this one in the config in logback --
```<logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>```

Comment: I tried and the issue stil exist. Do I miss something important?

Comment: in the pom.xml, you might have to exclude the log dependencies from spring starters.